# C# Xamarin Visual Studio Cancels Deploy

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, deployment

I installed a nuget package called: "SQLiteNetExtensions" and need it very much, but now when I click deploy, it builds, and deploys. After a while the bar in VS gets orange and the app is starting up, but then the bar gets blue again, the simulator closes the app, and everything is back to normal. I added a breakpoint to the first line in MainActivity.cs inside the OnCreate. But the it never comes that far. What can I do?

Comment: Look in the Application Output window and see if there are any hints on what is going on there.

Comment: Check your app target android version and minimum android version. Make sure they are compatible your simulator's android version.